# Simple way to convert expression to a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I know that I can convert an expression to list by

```
List @@ expr
```

But this does not work if `expr` is atomic, e.g.,

```
List @@ 1
```

will give you `1` instead of `{1}`. Of course I can check the length of `expr` first. But I wonder if there is simpler way to do this.

Comment: "But this does not work if `expr` contains only one term" - perhaps you meant to say that `expr` is *atomic*; `List @@ f[1]` works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like J.M. wrote, the question is if the expression is atomic, because `Apply` doesn't work on atomic expressions.
If we disambiguate the two cases we should be fine:

```
Listify = If[AtomQ[#], {#}, List @@ #]&

Listify[42]
(* {42} *)

Listify[foo[1, 2, 3]]
(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
ClearAll[toList]
toList = # /. { _[a__] :> {a}, a_?AtomQ :> {a}} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {2, a, foo[a, b], s + t + u, Rational[1, 3], 
   Complex[5, 6], <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>, DateObject[]};

Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{list, toList /@ list}], 
  Item[#, Background -> LightBlue] & /@ {"expr", "toList@expr"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {42, a, f[1, 2, 3], {1, 2, 3}};
```

Using `Replace`

```
List @@@ Replace[list, x_?AtomQ :> {x}, {1}]
```

{{42}, {a}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = {42, a, f[1, 2, 3], {1, 2, 3}};

list2 = {2, a, foo[a, b], s + t + u, Rational[1, 3], 
         Complex[5, 6], <|a -> x, b -> y, c -> z|>, DateObject[]};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `Cases` and `Map`:

```
list1 // Map[Cases[{#}, x_ /; AtomQ[x], {0, ∞}] &]

(*{{42}, {a}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}*)
```

Generalizing the solution:

```
f1[expr_] := ReleaseHold@HoldForm[Attributes][Head[expr]]

f2[expr_] /; f1[expr] =!= {} && AtomQ[expr] || f1[expr] =!= {} 
          && ! AtomQ[expr] := expr /. s1_[s2__] | s2__ :> {s2}

f2[expr_] /; f1[expr] === {} := Cases[{expr}, x_ /; AtomQ[x], {0, ∞}]

f2 /@ list2 === toList /@ list2

(*True*)
```