# Extracting elements from a List in a specific way

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have a set of polynomial expressions in multiple variables:

```
U = x[1] x[2] + x[1] x[3] + x[2] x[3]
F = m1^2 x[1]^2 x[2] + m2^2 x[1] x[2]^2 + m1^2 x[1]^2 x[3] + m1^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] + m2^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] + m3^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] - p^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] + m2^2 x[2]^2 x[3] + m3^2 x[1] x[3]^2 + m3^2 x[2] x[3]^2
G = U + F
```

The relevant variables in this case (and for all of my examples) are the various "x[i]"-s, where "i" is an integer.

To split the terms in `G`, I use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222110/53486) answer.

```
ClearAll[toList]
toList = # /. {_[a__] :> {a}, a_?AtomQ :> {a}} &;
listresG = toList[G];
```

**What I need**:
A way to extract the terms appearing in `U` and `F` from the expression of `G`. I find doing this non-trivial since Mathematica sum does some kind of monomial ordering of its own that might change the place of each term. For eg, in this example, the explicit expression for `G` happens to be

```
G = x[1] x[2] + m1^2 x[1]^2 x[2] + m2^2 x[1] x[2]^2 + x[1] x[3] + m1^2 x[1]^2 x[3] + x[2] x[3] + m1^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] + m2^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] + m3^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] - p^2 x[1] x[2] x[3] + m2^2 x[2]^2 x[3] + m3^2 x[1] x[3]^2 + m3^2 x[2] x[3]^2
```

which has clearly altered the positioning of the terms relative to where they appear in `U` and `F`.

I have tried doing `Cases[listresG, x[_Integer]*x[_Integer]]` to extract the terms appearing in `U` from `G`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example of desired outcome, perhaps on a simpler sample expression? I find it quite difficult to follow your description of the process. Additionally, have you considered a more processing-friendly format for your variables? For instance, it is commonly recommended to replace `Subscript[x, n]` with just `x[n]` and double index variables with e.g. `x[n, m]` or `x[n][m]`. The latter formulations are much easier for pattern matching, substitution, etc.

Comment: @MarcoB Please check the modified question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UTerms = List @@ U
(*{x[1] x[2], x[1] x[3], x[2] x[3]}*)

FTerms = List @@ F
(*{m1^2 x[1]^2 x[2], m2^2 x[1] x[2]^2, m1^2 x[1]^2 x[3], 
 m1^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], m2^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], 
 m3^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], -p^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], m2^2 x[2]^2 x[3], 
 m3^2 x[1] x[3]^2, m3^2 x[2] x[3]^2}*)

GTerms = List @@ G
(*{x[1] x[2], m1^2 x[1]^2 x[2], m2^2 x[1] x[2]^2, x[1] x[3], 
 m1^2 x[1]^2 x[3], x[2] x[3], m1^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], 
 m2^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], m3^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], -p^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], 
 m2^2 x[2]^2 x[3], m3^2 x[1] x[3]^2, m3^2 x[2] x[3]^2}*)
```

I"m not 100% clear what you are meaning by "terms".
If you mean terms in the sum then:

```
UinG = Intersection[Gterms, UTerms]
(*{x[1] x[2], x[1] x[3], x[2] x[3]}*)

FinG = Intersection[Gterms, FTerms]
(*{m1^2 x[1]^2 x[2], m2^2 x[1] x[2]^2, m1^2 x[1]^2 x[3], 
 m1^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], m2^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], 
 m3^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], -p^2 x[1] x[2] x[3], m2^2 x[2]^2 x[3], 
 m3^2 x[1] x[3]^2, m3^2 x[2] x[3]^2}*)
```

If that's not what you meant, let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER

To amplify upon MarcoB's comment about indexed variables:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To format specified indexed variables (e.g., `x` and `m`) as subscripts use

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {x, m};

U = x[1] x[2] + x[1] x[3] + x[2] x[3]
```

[image]

```
F = (-p^2 + m[1]^2 + m[2]^2 + m[3]^2) x[1] x[2] x[3] + 
  m[3]^2 (x[1] + x[2]) x[3]^2 + m[2]^2 x[2]^2 (x[1] + x[3]) + 
  m[1]^2 x[1]^2 (x[2] + x[3])
```

[image]

```
G = x[1] x[2] + x[1] x[3] + 
  x[2] x[3] + (-p^2 + m[1]^2 + m[2]^2 + m[3]^2) x[1] x[2] x[3] + 
  m[3]^2 (x[1] + x[2]) x[3]^2 + m[2]^2 x[2]^2 (x[1] + x[3]) + 
  m[1]^2 x[1]^2 (x[2] + x[3])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

To gather terms from U and F in G, you may first transform the polynomials into lists and then use "GatherBy" checking for membership in e.g. U. This gives a one liner:

```
GatherBy[List @@ G, MemberQ[List @@ U, #] &]
```

[image]